# Eloquent ORM hasManyThrough for more than 1 segment

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent, relationship

Eloquent ORM hasManyThrough allows me to reach to objects that are 1 segement away. 
Is there a easy way to fetch objects than are more than 1 segment away?

For example I have objects like this:

```
account
survey
- account_id
respondent
- survey_id
content
- respondent_id
```

How would I be able to fetch content object for given account object?

Comment: No builtin method for this.

Answer (score 1):

Im not aware of any way to access 2 segments away using `hasManyThrough()`, but you could just eager load them if you have all of your relationships set up.

```
$accounts = Account::with('surveys.respondents.content')->get();
```